# SQL: eliminating duplicate rows in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. and i want to compare with two tables and remove duplicate values. But first i need to look up the 'A-Confirm-tbl' and if the id is confirm then only remove it from above table. I wrote a simple SQL Code But it didn't work.

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
FULL JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
AND A-Confirm-tbl.id='1'
GROUP BY A.id

A   B
1   2
5   1
2   5
3   4
10  8
20  15

A-Confirm-tbl
id  confirm
1   1
5   0
2   1
3   0
10  0
20  0
```

Comment: did you looked at this guide? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

Comment: yeah... but i need get the values. not to delete. and BTW i already searched. i need the code very urgently

Comment: `A-Confirm-tbl` is not exactly a valid table name...

Comment: Where you have 'A-Confirm-tbl.id='1'' should that be 'A-Confirm-tbl.confirm='1'' ?

Comment: Sorry its just an example table

Comment: you can union and select into another table, with select distinct

Answer (score 0):

Free Hand, but essentially I would just join the confirm table to get only the a rows that have the confirm value of 1 and then do a subselect to get all B ids and only select rows from A that have an ID from that sub select.

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A 
JOIN A-Confim-tbl aconf 
  ON A.id = aconf.id AND aconf.confirm = 1 
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT B.id FROM B)
```

Comment: again, I think this should probably be 'AND aconf.confirm = 1'

Answer (score 0):

I would do below:
Use inner join to find the match records id with tblA and tblB. Then join the records with A-Confirm-tbl , and filter the records with only confirm=1.

```
SELECT * from tblA a 
INNER JOIN tblB b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN A-Confim-tbl c on a.id=c.id 
WHERE c.confirm='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE first_table_name
FROM first_table_name
INNER JOIN second_table_name
      ON second_table_name.ID = first_table_name.ID
join A-Confim-tbl on first_table_name.ID=A-Confim-tbl.Id
where A-Confim-tbl.confirm='1'
```